# I execute lib task but it execute my app task befrore hand

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

:app:clean

:app-android-library:clean

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Above is the gradle console log

while my lib is provided,I should complie my lib first.Howerver when I execute
the lib task it begin the app task first.
I'm so confuesed and check my configuration are all aboslutly right!

Comment: This is the clean task, not the build task... It makes sense to me that cleaning happens in reverse order

Comment: well,I just show the cleaning case. when I execute the lib release task it execute the app task first,then it could't find the lib classes and end failure! what confused me is sometimes I just change the build tools version and sync,it will run normally,but sometimes this option would't work well.

Comment: I doubt there are something wrong with the log "Configuration on demand is an incubating feature"